# Android application crashes at launch whenever I attach an onclicklistener to a button

Tags: android, button, crash, android-layout

Hey guys. I'm writing an app to retrieve last fm albums at the moment and whenever I attach an onclicklistener to my button, created in search_layout.xml, it crashes at launch. If I comment out the listener, it doesn't crash. Heres the code:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity{

//data members
private EditText movieName;
private Button okayBut;
private Button cancelBut;
private URL url;
private InputStream in;
private TextView tv;
private LastFMAlbumHandler lfmah;
private Vector<String> parsedVector;
private String picUrlString;
private URL picUrl;
private SearchActivity search;
private RelativeLayout layout;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initalize variables below
    movieName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);        
    okayBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    cancelBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    search = this;



 this.okayBut.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//      
            try{
//                      url = new URL("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
//                      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                      in = conn.getInputStream(); //now  global variable, was bufferedInputStream
//                      try{
//                          lfmah = new LastFMAlbumHandler(tv);
//                          parseToHandler(in, lfmah);
//                          parsedVector = lfmah.getResults();
//                          for(int i = 0; i < parsedVector.size(); i++)
//                          {
//                              picUrlString = parsedVector.get(i);
//                              picUrl = new URL(picUrlString);
//                              imgGet imageGet = new imgGet(layout, picUrl, search);
//                              imageGet.run();
//                          }
//                      }
//                      catch (Exception e){
//                          //fresh.append("couldn't parse");
//                      }
//                      finally{
//                          in.close();
//                      }
//                  }catch(Exception e){
//                      tv.append("could not connect");
//                  } 
            }
     });    
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);
}

//ParseToHandler method
private void parseToHandler(InputStream in, CheapHandler handler) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
{
    try{
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(in, handler);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        tv.append("first");
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        tv.append("second");
    }
    catch (SAXException e)
    {
        tv.append("third");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tv.append("unknown");
    }
}

}
```

and here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/label" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter movie name below:" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/entry" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_below="@id/label" />

<Button android:id="@+id/ok" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button android:id="@+id/cancel" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok" android:text="Cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning your onClickListener to the button before you've called setContentView so the button will be 'null' at that point, i.e., the layout hasn't been inflated yet.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't the `setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);` be located before the code that calls `findViewById`?

Answer (score 2):

Move the call to `setContentView` so it comes before any of the calls to `findViewById`. Until you call `setContentView`, none of those ids will be found.

Also, making a network connection is a time-consuming operation. You should not do it in a click handler (or anywhere on the event thread). Move the that part of the code to a separate thread and start use `onClick()` to start the thread. See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
setContentView(R.layout.search_layout)
```

this should precede your

```
 //initalize variables below 
movieName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);         
okayBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok); 
cancelBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel); 
layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout); 
search = this;
```

You should use AsyncTask to make the requests to the server as the data requests cannot be made on the main UI thread after Android Api Level 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your onClickListener and Button

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_configup1);        
button.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);` before calling any of the `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the listener within `onStart` fixed `null pointer` problems for me.

Maybe views/fragments aren't inflated until after onCreate now...